# Using regex to find lines which start with AND end with heart

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to use regex to find lines within a file that start with AND end with the same word; 'heart'.

What I have so far is:

```
grep '^\bheart\b' file.txt
```

This matches the word at the start of a line with 'heart' but I cannot seem to get the second half of this command to match if the end of the line is also 'heart'.

My expected results should match: 'heart', 'heart to heart' for example.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `grep -E '^heart\b(.*\bheart)?$' file` if you also expect matches where `heart` is a single word on a line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using

```
grep -E '^heart\b(.*\bheart)?$' file > result_file
```

The pattern will also find a match where a whole word `heart` is a single word on a line.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `heart` - a word `heart`
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(.*\bheart)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars
  - `\bheart` - a whole word `heart`
- `$` - end of a string.